# Issue with Mod_Rewrite after moving projects out of "www" "folder from WampServer

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I've been trying for a few hours and cannot get around to why an out-of-box WordPress instance with Permalinks enabled works when it is in `"C:\wamp\www"` whereas the same duplicate will receive a "404 Not Found" when place in a folder outside of `"www"` folder, say `"C:\projects"`?

I believe the `httpd-vhosts.conf` is configured correctly, but just in case here's a paste of the 2 vhost setups.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "C:\wamp\www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot    "C:\wamp\www\wordpress-lorem"
    ServerName      wordpress-lorem.localhost.com
    <Directory "C:\wamp\www\wordpress-lorem">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot    "C:\Projects\wordpress-ipsum"
    ServerName      wordpress-ipsum.localhost.com
    <Directory "C:\Projects\wordpress-ipsum">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

- Site `wordpress-lorem.localhost.com` will work problem free.
- While `wordpress-ipsum.localhost.com` will have problem with its permalinks (works fine when permalinks are switched off).

Experimented on Windows 8.1 64-bit and WampServer 2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the "AllowOverride All" In the directory section in the additional vhost. This prevents your htaccess from working...

Comment: That was it, Thank you!! Can you further elaborate why "AllowOverride All" is required only when the website instance is outside of `"www"` folder?

Comment: It's required everywhere... It's in the wamp configuration that you paste, first line in the Directory of the ServerName localhost. The fact you didn't need it in the second vhost, is because the first one is setting it for the base folder so it's inherited from there since it's a subfolder.